# ProgressBar INVISIBLE

Tags: java, android

Есть список изображений, сделанный через RecyclerView. Когда вы нажимаете на изображение, в то время пока оно передается в следующую активити, должен отображаться ProgressBar. Когда происходит возврат к активности выбора изображения, ProgressBar также остается видимым, хотя он должен быть скрыт.

Как я сделал ниже, прогресс становится невидимым только на первом изображении, но на остальных он не работает(остается видимым). Я не могу понять почему

**в моем проекте есть такие классы как**

**interface**

```
public interface ImageOnC {
    void onClick(int position);
}
```

**ImageViewHolder**

```
public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    private ImageOnC imageOnC;
    public ImageButton imageButton;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public void setImageOnC(ImageOnC imageOnC) {
        this.imageOnC = imageOnC;
    }

    public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_outline);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progr);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageOnC.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ImageAdabter**

```
public class ImageAdabter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Integer> listImages;

    public ImageAdabter(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listImages = getImages();
    }

    private List<Integer> getImages() {
        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

        results.add(R.drawable.outline1);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline2);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline3);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline4);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline5);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline6);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline7);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline8);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline9);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline10);

        return  results;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_images,parent,false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource( listImages.get(position));
        holder.setImageOnC(new ImageOnC() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                Common.PICTURE_SELECTED = listImages.get(position);
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, Colorful.class));
            }
        });


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object>payload){
    //if so, then the progress bar only works for the first image in recyclerview
        if(!payload.isEmpty()){
            if(payload.get(position) instanceof Integer)
                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        else super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payload);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listImages.size();
    }
}
```

**Это я добавляю в активити**

```
private void initView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_images);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adabter = new ImageAdabter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adabter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adabter != null) {
        adabter.notifyItemChanged(position, position);
    }
}
```

Если делать таким образом, то прогрессбар работает как нужно только у первого изображения..

Comment: установите в xml visibility = gone а когда нужно показывайте

Comment: с gone тоже не работает

Comment: Интерфейс public interface ImageOnC {
    void onClick(int pos);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашему адаптеру в конструкторе не нужен ни контекст ни список. 
Так же будет правильно реализовывать клик во `фрагменте/активити` просто передавая через интерфейс ссылку на айтем.
`Контекст` для картинок можно брать `у любой вью`, так же и список передавать в конструктор вовсе `не нужно`. Вместо этого можно создать внутри адаптера метод, например такой :

```
 fun setData(item: List<Integer>){
    listImages.clear()
    listImages.addAll(item)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

и создавать адаптер проще :

```
adapter = new Adapter()
```

и добавлять данные :

```
adapter.getData(listImages)
```

В этот же момент каждый раз адаптер будет получать notifyDataSetChange()
Ну и следовательно там же можно установить флаг на показ прогресс бара.
можно ,как советовали выше создать еще методы для обновления удаления итд.

к примеру вам нужно сделать какой то метод в котором либо показывать либо прятать прогресс бар только там где нужно. Если речь идет о адаптере, то пользоваться позицией.
Например

```
override fun showProgress(show: Boolean) {
    if (show) {
        progressBar.visibility = VISIBLE;
    } else {
        progressBar.visibility = GONE;
    }
}
```

соответственно обновленный метод будет выглядить так

```
    fun setData(item: List<Integer>){
        listImages.clear()
        listImages.addAll(item)
showProgress(false)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Вообще вся эта идея с показом выглядит как костыль, но можно еще прикрутить таймер для показа видимости на секунду две))))
Можно прикрутить еще таймер для видимости загрузки на пару секунд как костыль.

Ну а показывать нужный по позиции как вы и делали/

Так же, если нужно показывать загрузку пока загружаются картинки и вообще для загрузки картинок в целом можно воспользоваться PICASSO или GLIDE
Специально обученные люди специально обученным инструменами сделали их специально для загрузки изображений.
Там есть свои коллбэки для отработки этих событий

```
try {
        if (urlToImage != null && urlToImage.isNotEmpty()) {
            Picasso.get()
                .load(urlToImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placehoder)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.image, object : Callback {
                    override fun onSuccess() {
                        if (holder.progressBar != null) {
                            holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Exception) {}
                })
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, Вы правы, это КОСТЫЛЬ)) Через таймер я уже делал, хотелось сделать правильно чтоли)

Comment: Что бы вам сделать правильно , нужно немного поменять логику

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я вижу из кода у вас список на базе recyclerView. Я думаю что нужно использовать такую штуку как `notifyItemChanged`. В конструктор вы передаете интерфейс который нужен для того чтобы адаптер как-то был связан с активностью. Поэтому вероятнее всего ваша активность имеет функцию `onClick` или что-то типа того, куда вы передаете позицию картинки. Следовательно позиция у вас есть и вы можете вызвать такой метод:

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position, 0)
```

дальше в адаптере списка нужно переопределить метод:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HelloViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payload) {
if(!payloads.isEmpty()) {
   if (payloads.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
      holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE;
   }
}else {
   super.onBindViewHolder(holder,position, payloads);
}
}
```

таким образом как только вы передали данные в активность, то вы сразу скрываете ваш лоадер.
И я бы вам советовал сделать обработку картинки в методу `onBindViewHolder` так как там будет удобнее брать position картинки.

Comment: просто у вас в  ImageViewHolder есть слушатель нажатий который показывает лоадер, но тем не менее так же добавьте второй метод onBindViewHolder и обрабатывайте приходящие данные с активности :)

Comment: Да, это работает, но только с первой картинкой в списке

Comment: а с остальными что не так? передавайте позицию и обрабатывайте все картинки

Comment: Передаю position, но также только пргрессбар на первой картинке становится невидимым...Не могу понять почему)

Comment: а вы через логи можете посмотреть какая позиция передается и какой идентификатор действия?

Comment: то есть у вас только у первой картинки скрывается бар при возврате на активность со списком, а если нажимать на другую картинку и при возврате бар все еще крутится, я правильно понял?

Comment: именно так как вы написали, т.е. бар на каждой картинке, на первой при возврате все хорошо, на остальных, бар крутится

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107800/discussion-between-andrew-and-freedom).